# Adobe CQ5.5 using node identifier pass around resource references

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

I'm trying to figure out to retrieve a jcr resource via it's identifier. Basically I'm doing the following.

component1

```
String compID = resource.adaptTo(Node.class).getIdentifier();
```

then when it gets passed to component2 I would like to retrieve component1. If it helps i'm passing the identifier via Query String Parameters to help support some other client requirements.

component2

```
//code to get id from query string
//want to do something like:

Node resNode = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Node.class);
Session jcrSession = resNode.getSession();
Resource myRes = jcrSession.getNodeByIdentifier(eventId).adaptTo(Resource.class);

//use myRes as I please.
```

The 2nd example of course doesn't work, and I realize that Node does not have adaptTo support. So I am more or less curious if anyone can shed some light on how I could accomplish what my component2 example is failing to do.

thank you,
Brodie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should adapt `ResourceResolver` directly to a `Session`. Then get a node by the identifier. There is no way to create `Resource` from the `Node`, so use `Node` path and get the `Resource` from the `ResourceResolver`:

```
Session jcrSession = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
Node node = jcrSession.getNodeByIdentifier(eventId);
Resource resource = resourceResolver.getResource(node.getPath());
```

Comment: Yup this is what I ended up doing :D

Comment: I'm pretty surprised that there's no utility class or anything in CQ that offers a more efficient way to get a Resource based on a Node. Is this still the case with CQ5.6?